# Remove characters from the beginning of an NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have an `NSString`

```
NSString *data = @"abcdefghi";
```

but I want the data to be the `"defghi"`

What can I do to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do :

```
NSMutableString *data = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"abcdefghi"];
[data deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
```

This is using [NSMutableString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which allows you to delete and add Characters/Strings to itself.

The method used here is [deleteCharactersInRange](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/deleteCharactersInRange%3a) this deletes the letters in the `NSRange`, in this case the range has a `location` of `0`, so that it starts at the start, and a `length` of `3`, so it deletes 3 letters in.

Comment: You can't initialise an `NSMutableString` like that, you must use `[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"abcdefghi"]`.

Comment: Thanks, just realized that. Edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
[data substringFromIndex:2]
```

this will return a new String with the characters up to the index (2) clipped.

Comment: this will not delete the chars from that string, rather it will create a new string. though it is sufficient for many cases :-)

Comment: Also, `[data substringFromIndex:3]` is what the author wants, since the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_124) says that the given index is included in the result.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be NSScanner if you don't know the exact location of your chars you want to delete: [Apple Guide to NSScanners](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-BCIEFGHC). You might want to look at the rest of the guide as well, as it very good describes what you can do with a string in Obj-C.

Answer (score 0):

NSString is immutable. You need to use NSMutableString unless you want to create a new string. Look at [deleteCharactersInRange](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/deleteCharactersInRange:) method.